# If then based on label

Tags: python, scripting

Tried to search the forum already for some time, but can't get something working in a script in my blender environment. I want to play an animation based on the content of a label. I am really struggling with the if and elif condition, especially with the content of a label. Can anybody provide a simple example?

I have now this, but it doesn't work:

```py
import bpy
status = bpy.data.objects["Text"]
if status == 'GO':
    bpy.ops.screen.animation_play()
elif status == 'NOGO':
    bpy.ops.screen.animation_stop()
```

Comment: not a direct answer to the question, but this might solve the origin problem that you are not "reading" the text, but accessing the text object, which in turns contains `data` information, which in turn contains the `body`of the text, which you are looking for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17388912/blender-script-how-to-write-to-text-object and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6288/can-python-be-used-to-edit-a-text-object

Comment: tldr : replace `bpy.data.objects["Text"]` by `bpy.data.objects["Text"].data.body`

Comment: thanks, that did the job!