# How to do parametrized rendering (replacing text/image inputs dynamically before render)

Tags: rendering, text-object, command-line

I am currently generating a dynamic blender file with 2 text and 1 image objects that should be replaced with custom text/image inputs.

I currently got the CLI command and placement of text/image objects - the next task is now figuring out how to replace these from reading an external file/input.

Ideal end-goal would be something like

`./generate-script --text1 "Hello world" --text2 "EFGH" --img "./some.png"` which will run the replacement command + `blender` render CLI command.

After reading the docs, the direction I should head towards seem to be writing custom python scripts/addons (and found a relevant question here: [Can python be used to edit a Text Object?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6288/can-python-be-used-to-edit-a-text-object)). Next question would be how would I fit this script into as part of the command line rendering steps? Would it be `run python script` => `run blender render script`?

Also if there is an easier way to achieve this, I am all ears as well. Any guidance would be useful here :)

Comment: Probably have the text data block as script_one in the blend file, then use the command line option —python-text script_one